# How to check both in C++ and C#, if I'm inside the instance of class/struct?

Tags: .net, class, struct, polymorphism, instance

I wonder, how can I check both in C++ and C# , if my code is executing inside the instance of class/struct?

I need such option to make some members of class/struct be visible only if I have created the instance of class and no other way, and only in this instance (even for class functions they aren't visible only if I have created the instance of it).

Comment: looks strange from design standpoint, why any class should encapsulate such logic, perhaps some separate class should be aware of this verification/limitation logic, take  a look at the mediator design patter

Comment: In c# there is no such thing as "the instance" of a struct - it will copy itself at whim

Comment: Why in C# there is no such thing? As I remember, if I create the instance of struct, I shall allocate memory from stack, not from heap.

And in unsafe mode, I can use ( A is some struct ): A obj1 = new A(); A* obj2 = &obj1; obj1 - is instance, whicj uses stack, obj2 - is pointer on obj1 instance

Comment: Do you need this in run-time or design-time? If second you can use a keyword **static**.

Comment: static? staic is simple stuff from singleton

I mean, if I have class or another structure (struct/union)

How can I make some members be visible only in instace of this class?

And about Marc's conlusion... And so what about class? Arent's instance of classes/struct - just it's copies which allocates memory from stack or heap? And so what?

Comment: and instance is such stuff which is presented as some stuff, which helps you to use the methods and etc from the copy of the class/struct ( which was allocated from stack/heap ) you have created

Answer (score 0):

Strange Question, though let me try answering it:

**To make some members of class/struct be visible only if I have created the instance**:

> Visible to who ?

In C# programming language , non-Static members are avaialble on an instance of the class only if they are marked as public (private/protected/internal are also avaialble on the basis of where you are created instance of the class).

So if i get it correctly when you are asking **visibility** you meant visible on instance of the class. In C# , Visibility is controlled by public/private/protected/internal keywords and not by some logic.

**how can I check both in C++ and C# , if my code is executing inside the instance of class**

If your method is not static , you can always say that it is executing under instance of the class only. there is no other way by which your code can be executed.